# Simple transformer by huggingface dump using joblib

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, gdrive

I've got a question about dumping a simple transofmer model.

I trained a model, than dump it using joblib :

```
dump(model, 'Simple_transfomers.joblib')
```

and when I load it in the other script using :

```
files = glob.glob('Simple_transfomers.joblib')

model = ClassificationModel(
    "bert", "models/files"
)
```

or even tried other way :

```
model = ClassificationModel(
    "bert", "outputs/pytorch_model.bin"
)
```

I recieved :

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/*outputs/pytorch_model.bin*/resolve/main/config.json
```

I think the problem could be using google colab and store the model on google drive.

Is there any possibility to read the gdrive directory using ClassificationModel ?

Read the docs on https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/usage/ but cannot find any solution.

Comment: [Here](https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/colab/2020/05/09/Colab-mounting-google-drive.md/) There is a great explanation on how to use Gdrive for dump/load files in google colab

Answer (score 0):

If your `dump` there is joblib.dump, you can simply use `joblib.load`

```
model = joblib.load("Simple_transfomers.joblib")
```

`joblib` is like pickle (it even uses pickle I think) that dumps a python object to a file.